# DataFrame append problems

Tags: python, pandas, pdf

I am iterating through lot of PDF, parsing, and capturing data with Regex and transforming it into a DataFrame and then exporting to CSV. I then create an additional column that contains the name of the file from which the data came from. I then wanted to append it to a dummy DataFrame in which I will accumulate all the data. But it seems I am using the append function wrong because the output is the original dummy DataFrame. What am I doing wrong?

So the goal is to create an DataFrame of the parsed data with a column indicating from which file the data came from

PS: I know this is a pretty clumsy solution with the dummy DataFrame and am very open to all suggestions how to make it better!

```
import os
import glob
from tika import parser
import re
import pandas as pd
from functools import reduce

final = pd.DataFrame([["1", "2", "3"]], columns = ['File', 'Raum', 'Flaeche']) 


for input_file in glob.glob(os.path.join(input_path, '*.pdf')):
    print(input_file)
    parserPDF = parser.from_file(input_file)
    pdf = parserPDF['content']
    split = pdf.splitlines()
    split2 = [x for x in split if x.strip()]
    split3 = str(split2)

    raumbuch = re.findall(r'\'([^\']+)\'\,\s\'(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?\s?m[2²])', split3)

    df = pd.DataFrame(raumbuch)
    df['File'] = os.path.basename(input_file)
    df.columns = ["Datei", "Raum","Flaeche"]

    final.append(df)

print(final)
```

OUTPUT:

```
  Datei Raum Flaeche
0     1    2       3
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
final = final.append(df)
```

or

```
final_data = pd.concat([final_data, df], axis=0)
```

Hope this will help!!